# Want to use patterns in traefik health check not just being alive but healthy

Tags: traefik, traefik-authentication, traefik-middleware, traefik-routers, traefik-plugins

Is there any way to use a pattern for health check using traefik? for example based on some value in json response ( UP or ready or so )?-- Not using kuber

I tries to use health check but it did not allow me to use my pattern....

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, no. [See here](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/services/#health-check) for the available options.

You can set up an endpoint in your service that only returns `2XX` or `3XX` if the service is ready to accept requests (and `503` otherwise).